# Chances a forecasting model exceeds/deceeds a specified threshold

Tags: forecasting, prediction, volatility-forecasting

I am interested in determining the confidence of a forecasting model with applications to quantitative finance.

I have the following multivariate data $X$:

\begin{align}
    X(t) \sim F_{X}(t)
\end{align}

where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{T, d}$ for $T$ timesteps in $d$ dimensions.

I am interested in a forecasting problem:

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& \textrm{Given: } X = \{x_{i,:}\}_{i=0}^{T-1} \textrm{ timeseries data} \\
& \textrm{Determine: } X^f = \{x_{{i, :}}\}_{i > T-1} \textrm{ the values of the timeseries at future timesteps}
\end{split}
\end{align}

To answer this question, I am interested in using multivariate ARMA (as well as AR and MA)-type models, GARCH models, LSTM (long-short term memory ANN), or BNN (bayesian neural network), and am open to "more suitable" approaches.

I am particularly interested in quantifying the confidence at which a given prediction for one feature in my timeseries exceeding/deceeding/equaling a specified value. Mathematically, the following quantity:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left\{R\left(\mathbb{P}\left\{X^f_{:, q}, i > T-1\right\}, c\right)\right\}
\end{align}

at some point in $X^f$ the timeseries for feature $q$ exceeds/deceeds $c$ in the future arbitrarily,
-or-

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left\{R\left(\mathbb{P}\left\{x_{i, q}, i > T-1\right\}, c\right)\right\}
\end{align}

the chances that a specific $x_i$ at timepoint $i$ in the future for feature $q$ exceeds/deceeds $c$.

where $R(a, b)$ is a relation on $a, b$ and can be either greater than ($R(a, b) := \mathbb{I}\left\{a>b\right\}$) or less than ($R(a, b) := \mathbb{I}\left\{a<b\right\}$). It feels to me like given a parametrized model, this quantity should be easy to estimate analytically.

Does anybody know how this can be effectively done analytically for the given models specified? Is there a simple, easily-generalizable to parametrized (or possibly less-interpretable models like a RNN) this could be done empirically through simulation? If there is good literature on the topic, that would work too. I've researched around a bit but haven't yet found anything quite worthwhile.

One possible empirical way to do it that I've thought up so far is to jitter the values sensibly to form the null. For example, construct a volatility model on the variance of inputs which produces an estimate of the variance based on the past-history at a given point in time, and jitter the inputs by the time-varying estimates of variance. Or something like that. Then, through simulation generate a synthetic range of forecasts from models individually trained on the jittered input. Output confidence as the number of times the forecast on jittered data exceeds/deceeds a user-defined quantity.

Are there any better models that could be used for this problem? I am an R/python programmer, so implementation links would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was recently added to AUTOBOX ( a commercially available piece of software that I have helped to develop ). The idea is straightforward ..identify a parsimonious ARIMA model which includes dummy indicators to reflect pulses, level/step shifts, seasonal pulses and local time trends using homogeneous recent data that has parameters that are invariant over time which has yielded an error process that is homogeneous over time. Resmaple/bootstrap the i.i.d model residuals to create simulations for each period in the future. Review the cdf of the simulated forecasts to identify the probability of exceeding/deceeding a user-specified value.

Things get a little trickier when you have incorporated schemes to deal with time varying error variance and the effect of user specified predictor series which have to be predicted ...think convolution ...

Comment: so this sounds quite similar to what i've proposed, then, with better restrictions on the model than i've stated? when you say "resample/bootstrap the iid model residuals" you mean just basically to retrain the model on an input resampled according to the residuals to create cdf of simulated forecasts, right? sorry; very new to forecasting, so i might be misinterpretting :P

Comment: no retraining of the model ... use n observations to get model parameters and one set of residuals.. use those residuals to create a number of pseudo--residuals and use these pseudo residuals as perturbations to get potential realizations. compute cdf of these potential realizations to get probability point for a particular forecast point. If you are forecasting out a number of periods you will have to incorporate the psi-weights of the model to incorporate the possibly expanded uncertainty. This can get can get complicated ..essentailly speaking to your "time-varying variance" comment.

Comment: can you call me ..so we can dialogue on this ...

Comment: oh; so purturb the forecasts of the trained model, more or less? how are those "pseudo-residuals" constructed, and how do they weigh in? so:

1) use residuals on the training data to obtain a cdf of residuals

2) bootstrap forecasts empirically at each forecast point using cdf of residuals on the training data to obtain potential realizations

3) repeat bootstrapping procedure n times to obtain empirical estimate of null

like that?

Comment: great! number via PM? is that a thing on here?